# How can I write On Chain Contract Calls in Tezos Sandbox?

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson, smartpy, contract

I am trying to write a test case in Tezos Sandbox that uses an On Chain Contract Call. To start with, I am trying to implement the example from SmartPy "On Chain Contract Calls - Collatz" from the reference example.

I can originate the three contracts (OnEven, OnOdd, Collatz at the bottom for reference) successfully, however when I run the main Collatz contract with '42' as the input, I get the following error:

```
    (venv) $ poetry run python3 test_collatz.py 
# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-node identity generate 0.0 --data-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-node.7e5dk4oc
Generating a new identity... (level: 0.00)        
Stored the new identity (idsbZ4AcTjLUTgzQQAXKpFwRM31MUX) into '/var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-node.7e5dk4oc/identity.json'.

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-node config init --data-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-node.7e5dk4oc --net-addr 127.0.0.1:19730 --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:18730 --expected-pow 0.0 --connections 500 --bootstrap-threshold 0 --private-mode --network sandbox
Created /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-node.7e5dk4oc/config.json for network: sandbox.

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-node run --data-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-node.7e5dk4oc --no-bootstrap-peers --connections 500 --bootstrap-threshold 0 --private-mode --network sandbox --peer 127.0.0.1:19730 --peer 127.0.0.1:19731 --peer 127.0.0.1:19732 --peer 127.0.0.1:19733 --peer 127.0.0.1:19734 --peer 127.0.0.1:19735 --peer 127.0.0.1:19736 --peer 127.0.0.1:19737 --peer 127.0.0.1:19738 --peer 127.0.0.1:19739 --peer 127.0.0.1:19740 --peer 127.0.0.1:19741 --peer 127.0.0.1:19742 --peer 127.0.0.1:19743 --peer 127.0.0.1:19744 --peer 127.0.0.1:19745 --peer 127.0.0.1:19746 --peer 127.0.0.1:19747 --peer 127.0.0.1:19748 --peer 127.0.0.1:19749 --peer 127.0.0.1:19750 --peer 127.0.0.1:19751 --peer 127.0.0.1:19752 --peer 127.0.0.1:19753 --peer 127.0.0.1:19754 --peer 127.0.0.1:19755 --peer 127.0.0.1:19756 --peer 127.0.0.1:19757 --peer 127.0.0.1:19758 --peer 127.0.0.1:19759 --peer 127.0.0.1:19760 --peer 127.0.0.1:19761 --peer 127.0.0.1:19762 --peer 127.0.0.1:19763 --peer 127.0.0.1:19764 --peer 127.0.0.1:19765 --peer 127.0.0.1:19766 --peer 127.0.0.1:19767 --peer 127.0.0.1:19768 --peer 127.0.0.1:19769 --peer 127.0.0.1:19770 --peer 127.0.0.1:19771 --peer 127.0.0.1:19772 --peer 127.0.0.1:19773 --peer 127.0.0.1:19774
# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 rpc get /network/version
{ "chain_name": "TEZOS", "distributed_db_version": 0, "p2p_version": 1 }

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 -w none config update
# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 import secret key bootstrap1 unencrypted:edsk3gUfUPyBSfrS9CCgmCiQsTCHGkviBDusMxDJstFtojtc1zcpsh
Tezos address added: tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 import secret key bootstrap2 unencrypted:edsk39qAm1fiMjgmPkw1EgQYkMzkJezLNewd7PLNHTkr6w9XA2zdfo
Tezos address added: tz1gjaF81ZRRvdzjobyfVNsAeSC6PScjfQwN

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 import secret key bootstrap3 unencrypted:edsk4ArLQgBTLWG5FJmnGnT689VKoqhXwmDPBuGx3z4cvwU9MmrPZZ
Tezos address added: tz1faswCTDciRzE4oJ9jn2Vm2dvjeyA9fUzU

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 import secret key bootstrap4 unencrypted:edsk2uqQB9AY4FvioK2YMdfmyMrer5R8mGFyuaLLFfSRo8EoyNdht3
Tezos address added: tz1b7tUupMgCNw2cCLpKTkSD1NZzB5TkP2sv

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 import secret key bootstrap5 unencrypted:edsk4QLrcijEffxV31gGdN2HU7UpyJjA8drFoNcmnB28n89YjPNRFm
Tezos address added: tz1ddb9NMYHZi5UzPdzTZMYQQZoMub195zgv

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 import secret key baker1_key unencrypted:edsk432L71B91i1sE8rQxPDMo2Yxo4qaYqhktvpt8yovaMpo1NUbBt
Tezos address added: tz1UJbFsTQfdpa1qYrqHG9Ykw834AXi5WqRR

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 import secret key baker2_key unencrypted:edsk3jjD4cLvE1t3SiZKCRiH9SXnJ4jHEsVpfcuRwfe7sfbnsMGX6f
Tezos address added: tz1fWJ2oeeG6h2r61XY1wen2sV87AvCqGjAU

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 import secret key baker3_key unencrypted:edsk3EVDFeDsefk1UoWWhDhnBpERhAwqHbVzWnBwA4tdUL8aBhw7RC
Tezos address added: tz1SERFDUknkjJTas8sUco7dskxWrUWhTc2s

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 import secret key baker4_key unencrypted:edsk2rAmeBDrQ5d1FhDoTdifMvBsqSosmPSBhxL74huszZhfMFtiKb
Tezos address added: tz1eJ9yR95LmJgVrGLvgt56T6ngCFcgjLo2S

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 import secret key baker5_key unencrypted:edsk4Ssc63dnYJUptVMaKfmHLJNMBYv9piYiRCiYjcH3gacKWP1z3v
Tezos address added: tz1cwoRFe3BzJv9nZZBA5fk8uV6w9AVVrBF9

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 import secret key activator unencrypted:edsk31vznjHSSpGExDMHYASz45VZqXN4DPxvsa4hAyY8dHM28cZzp6
Tezos address added: tz1TGu6TN5GSez2ndXXeDX6LgUDvLzPLqgYV

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 -block genesis activate protocol ProtoALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaDdp3zK with fitness 1 and key activator and parameters /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tmp9oinifd6 --timestamp 2020-10-02T03:14:28Z
Injected BMX21PfKmNUf

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 remember contract baker1 SG1fpFaowYY8G7PfkYdKkGmsMziHKUfrHRHW
# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 remember contract baker2 SG1TLmKJHVJxQosY6iN21AW77HsAapdupxnR
# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 remember contract baker3 SG1hExdK69Z2RZkkQjKtLG6H4L4FGTZeGKHu
# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 remember contract baker4 SG1mHgeWHGMnCUMJ8jZ1Cdh3DkWEcQ88tziJ
# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 remember contract baker5 SG1jfZeHRzeWAM1T4zrwunEyUpwWc82D4tbv
# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-baker-alpha -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://127.0.0.1:18730 run with local node /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-node.7e5dk4oc baker5
# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 originate contract even_contract transferring 0 from bootstrap1 running collatz_even.tz --init Unit --burn-cap 9
Node is bootstrapped.
Estimated gas: 13465000 units (will add 100000 for safety)
Estimated storage: 376 bytes added (will add 20 for safety)
Operation successfully injected in the node.
Operation hash is 'onup8WwVpbKefbRQnSS4KfLKDj8gJnr63Dn1hsyCkQ8nx2piVNC'
NOT waiting for the operation to be included.
Use command
  tezos-client wait for onup8WwVpbKefbRQnSS4KfLKDj8gJnr63Dn1hsyCkQ8nx2piVNC to be included --confirmations 30 --branch BM1zDZAxWwwGxduLzdPtaNu6nr5MygyxjFpcJBbtoHpVYvZRRgY
and/or an external block explorer to make sure that it has been included.
This sequence of operations was run:
  Manager signed operations:
    From: tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx
    Fee to the baker: ꜩ0.001705
    Expected counter: 1
    Gas limit: 13565000
    Storage limit: 396 bytes
    Balance updates:
      tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx ................ -ꜩ0.001705
      fees(the baker who will include this operation,0) ... +ꜩ0.001705
    Origination:
      From: tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx
      Credit: ꜩ0
      Script:
        { parameter (pair (contract %k nat) (nat %x)) ;
          storage unit ;
          code { DUP ;
                 CDR ;
                 SWAP ;
                 CAR ;
                 DUP ;
                 CAR ;
                 NIL operation ;
                 SWAP ;
                 PUSH mutez 0 ;
                 PUSH nat 2 ;
                 DIG 4 ;
                 CDR ;
                 EDIV ;
                 IF_SOME { CAR } { PUSH int 14 ; FAILWITH } ;
                 TRANSFER_TOKENS ;
                 CONS ;
                 PAIR } }
        Initial storage: Unit
        No delegate for this contract
        This origination was successfully applied
        Originated contracts:
          KT1VFgSsVQF39GhYXU5wYEMygqAAd3vBGVkJ
        Storage size: 119 bytes
        Paid storage size diff: 119 bytes
        Consumed gas: 13465000
        Balance updates:
          tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx ... -ꜩ0.119
          tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx ... -ꜩ0.257

New contract KT1VFgSsVQF39GhYXU5wYEMygqAAd3vBGVkJ originated.
Contract memorized as even_contract.

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 bake for baker5 --minimal-timestamp
Injected block BM7cUBY5EDju

Oct  2 04:14:37.004 - alpha.baking.forge: found 1 valid operations (0 refused) for timestamp 2020-10-02T03:14:38-00:00 (fitness 01::0000000000000005)

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 originate contract odd_contract transferring 0 from bootstrap1 running collatz_odd.tz --init Unit --burn-cap 9
Node is bootstrapped.
Estimated gas: 13083000 units (will add 100000 for safety)
Estimated storage: 357 bytes added (will add 20 for safety)
Operation successfully injected in the node.
Operation hash is 'op8cRTdDJ8xtRVsNAMzKW8mTP5PZs4UMR71cbesPKqXDYrLuoZr'
NOT waiting for the operation to be included.
Use command
  tezos-client wait for op8cRTdDJ8xtRVsNAMzKW8mTP5PZs4UMR71cbesPKqXDYrLuoZr to be included --confirmations 30 --branch BM7cUBY5EDju7Mmj6TFofCua7WLsznaWrVRsbnF1jD1KCDNDwzf
and/or an external block explorer to make sure that it has been included.
This sequence of operations was run:
  Manager signed operations:
    From: tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx
    Fee to the baker: ꜩ0.001648
    Expected counter: 2
    Gas limit: 13183000
    Storage limit: 377 bytes
    Balance updates:
      tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx ................ -ꜩ0.001648
      fees(the baker who will include this operation,0) ... +ꜩ0.001648
    Origination:
      From: tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx
      Credit: ꜩ0
      Script:
        { parameter (pair (contract %k int) (int %x)) ;
          storage unit ;
          code { DUP ;
                 CDR ;
                 SWAP ;
                 CAR ;
                 DUP ;
                 CAR ;
                 NIL operation ;
                 SWAP ;
                 PUSH mutez 0 ;
                 PUSH int 1 ;
                 DIG 4 ;
                 CDR ;
                 PUSH int 3 ;
                 MUL ;
                 ADD ;
                 TRANSFER_TOKENS ;
                 CONS ;
                 PAIR } }
        Initial storage: Unit
        No delegate for this contract
        This origination was successfully applied
        Originated contracts:
          KT1KAVbJDYspe4RYZbrqbq7jDf8EVB7FLBdu
        Storage size: 100 bytes
        Paid storage size diff: 100 bytes
        Consumed gas: 13083000
        Balance updates:
          tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx ... -ꜩ0.1
          tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx ... -ꜩ0.257

New contract KT1KAVbJDYspe4RYZbrqbq7jDf8EVB7FLBdu originated.
Contract memorized as odd_contract.

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 bake for baker5 --minimal-timestamp
Injected block BLkjaU2VCQJk

Oct  2 04:14:37.815 - alpha.baking.forge: found 1 valid operations (0 refused) for timestamp 2020-10-02T03:14:40-00:00 (fitness 01::0000000000000006)

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 show known contract even_contract
KT1VFgSsVQF39GhYXU5wYEMygqAAd3vBGVkJ


# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 show known contract odd_contract
KT1KAVbJDYspe4RYZbrqbq7jDf8EVB7FLBdu


# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 originate contract main_contract transferring 0 from bootstrap1 running collatz_main.tz --init (Pair 0 (Pair "KT1VFgSsVQF39GhYXU5wYEMygqAAd3vBGVkJ" "KT1KAVbJDYspe4RYZbrqbq7jDf8EVB7FLBdu")) --burn-cap 9
Node is bootstrapped.
Estimated gas: 25053000 units (will add 100000 for safety)
Estimated storage: 853 bytes added (will add 20 for safety)
Operation successfully injected in the node.
Operation hash is 'ooomaEFrxKgSuE3xvEvckGR163xNz7oxUEhniSg2Pamy22ySGwQ'
NOT waiting for the operation to be included.
Use command
  tezos-client wait for ooomaEFrxKgSuE3xvEvckGR163xNz7oxUEhniSg2Pamy22ySGwQ to be included --confirmations 30 --branch BLkjaU2VCQJkyxev7Pt5CVoUoAcdgx3JopQKkKiMgzJi5Fvw825
and/or an external block explorer to make sure that it has been included.
This sequence of operations was run:
  Manager signed operations:
    From: tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx
    Fee to the baker: ꜩ0.003369
    Expected counter: 3
    Gas limit: 25153000
    Storage limit: 873 bytes
    Balance updates:
      tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx ................ -ꜩ0.003369
      fees(the baker who will include this operation,0) ... +ꜩ0.003369
    Origination:
      From: tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx
      Credit: ꜩ0
      Script:
        { parameter (or (unit %reset) (nat %run)) ;
          storage (pair (int %counter) (pair (address %onEven) (address %onOdd))) ;
          code { DUP ;
                 CDR ;
                 SWAP ;
                 CAR ;
                 IF_LEFT
                   { DROP ; CDR ; PUSH int 0 ; PAIR ; NIL operation }
                   { DUP ;
                     PUSH nat 1 ;
                     COMPARE ;
                     LT ;
                     IF { SWAP ;
                          DUP ;
                          CDR ;
                          SWAP ;
                          CAR ;
                          PUSH int 1 ;
                          ADD ;
                          PAIR ;
                          SWAP ;
                          PUSH nat 0 ;
                          PUSH nat 2 ;
                          DIG 2 ;
                          DUP ;
                          DUG 3 ;
                          EDIV ;
                          IF_SOME { CDR } { PUSH int 39 ; FAILWITH } ;
                          COMPARE ;
                          EQ ;
                          IF { NIL operation ;
                               DIG 2 ;
                               DUP ;
                               DUG 3 ;
                               CDAR ;
                               CONTRACT %run (pair (contract %k nat) (nat %x)) ;
                               IF_SOME {} { PUSH int 31 ; FAILWITH } ;
                               PUSH mutez 0 ;
                               DIG 3 ;
                               SELF ;
                               ADDRESS ;
                               CONTRACT %run nat ;
                               IF_SOME {} { PUSH int 33 ; FAILWITH } ;
                               PAIR %k %x ;
                               TRANSFER_TOKENS ;
                               CONS }
                             { NIL operation ;
                               DIG 2 ;
                               DUP ;
                               DUG 3 ;
                               CDDR ;
                               CONTRACT %run (pair (contract %k nat) (nat %x)) ;
                               IF_SOME {} { PUSH int 32 ; FAILWITH } ;
                               PUSH mutez 0 ;
                               DIG 3 ;
                               SELF ;
                               ADDRESS ;
                               CONTRACT %run nat ;
                               IF_SOME {} { PUSH int 33 ; FAILWITH } ;
                               PAIR %k %x ;
                               TRANSFER_TOKENS ;
                               CONS } }
                        { DROP ; NIL operation } } ;
                 PAIR } }
        Initial storage:
          (Pair 0
                (Pair "KT1VFgSsVQF39GhYXU5wYEMygqAAd3vBGVkJ" "KT1KAVbJDYspe4RYZbrqbq7jDf8EVB7FLBdu"))
        No delegate for this contract
        This origination was successfully applied
        Originated contracts:
          KT1QjwV6cjBX3umA7ZToNqkKpjbnCxXCcM1i
        Storage size: 596 bytes
        Paid storage size diff: 596 bytes
        Consumed gas: 25053000
        Balance updates:
          tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx ... -ꜩ0.596
          tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx ... -ꜩ0.257

New contract KT1QjwV6cjBX3umA7ZToNqkKpjbnCxXCcM1i originated.
Contract memorized as main_contract.

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 bake for baker5 --minimal-timestamp
Injected block BMZiyR2KKY33

Oct  2 04:14:39.321 - alpha.baking.forge: found 1 valid operations (0 refused) for timestamp 2020-10-02T03:14:42-00:00 (fitness 01::0000000000000007)

# /Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client -base-dir /var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on -endpoint http://localhost:18730 transfer 0 from bootstrap1 to main_contract --entrypoint run --burn-cap 9 --arg 42
Node is bootstrapped.
This simulation failed:
  Manager signed operations:
    From: tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx
    Fee to the baker: ꜩ0
    Expected counter: 4
    Gas limit: 1040000000
    Storage limit: 60000 bytes
    Transaction:
      Amount: ꜩ0
      From: tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx
      To: KT1QjwV6cjBX3umA7ZToNqkKpjbnCxXCcM1i
      Entrypoint: run
      Parameter: 42
      This operation FAILED.


Runtime error in contract KT1QjwV6cjBX3umA7ZToNqkKpjbnCxXCcM1i:
  01: { parameter (or (unit %reset) (nat %run)) ;
  02:   storage (pair (int %counter) (pair (address %onEven) (address %onOdd))) ;
  03:   code { DUP ;
  04:          CDR ;
  05:          SWAP ;
  06:          CAR ;
  07:          IF_LEFT
  08:            { DROP ; CDR ; PUSH int 0 ; PAIR ; NIL operation }
  09:            { DUP ;
  10:              PUSH nat 1 ;
  11:              COMPARE ;
  12:              LT ;
  13:              IF { SWAP ;
  14:                   DUP ;
  15:                   CDR ;
  16:                   SWAP ;
  17:                   CAR ;
  18:                   PUSH int 1 ;
  19:                   ADD ;
  20:                   PAIR ;
  21:                   SWAP ;
  22:                   PUSH nat 0 ;
  23:                   PUSH nat 2 ;
  24:                   DIG 2 ;
  25:                   DUP ;
  26:                   DUG 3 ;
  27:                   EDIV ;
  28:                   IF_SOME { CDR } { PUSH int 39 ; FAILWITH } ;
  29:                   COMPARE ;
  30:                   EQ ;
  31:                   IF { NIL operation ;
  32:                        DIG 2 ;
  33:                        DUP ;
  34:                        DUG 3 ;
  35:                        CDAR ;
  36:                        CONTRACT %run (pair (contract %k nat) (nat %x)) ;
  37:                        IF_SOME {} { PUSH int 31 ; FAILWITH } ;
  38:                        PUSH mutez 0 ;
  39:                        DIG 3 ;
  40:                        SELF ;
  41:                        ADDRESS ;
  42:                        CONTRACT %run nat ;
  43:                        IF_SOME {} { PUSH int 33 ; FAILWITH } ;
  44:                        PAIR %k %x ;
  45:                        TRANSFER_TOKENS ;
  46:                        CONS }
  47:                      { NIL operation ;
  48:                        DIG 2 ;
  49:                        DUP ;
  50:                        DUG 3 ;
  51:                        CDDR ;
  52:                        CONTRACT %run (pair (contract %k nat) (nat %x)) ;
  53:                        IF_SOME {} { PUSH int 32 ; FAILWITH } ;
  54:                        PUSH mutez 0 ;
  55:                        DIG 3 ;
  56:                        SELF ;
  57:                        ADDRESS ;
  58:                        CONTRACT %run nat ;
  59:                        IF_SOME {} { PUSH int 33 ; FAILWITH } ;
  60:                        PAIR %k %x ;
  61:                        TRANSFER_TOKENS ;
  62:                        CONS } }
  63:                 { DROP ; NIL operation } } ;
  64:          PAIR } }
At line 37 characters 50 to 58,
script reached FAILWITH instruction
with 31
Fatal error:
  transfer simulation failed

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_collatz.py", line 68, in <module>
    scenario_basic_call() 
  File "test_collatz.py", line 62, in scenario_basic_call
    '--arg', '42'])
  File "/Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tests_python/client/client.py", line 384, in transfer
    res = self.run(cmd)
  File "/Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tests_python/client/client.py", line 164, in run
    (stdout, _, _) = self.run_generic(params, admin, check, trace)
  File "/Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tests_python/client/client.py", line 153, in run_generic
    completed_process.check_returncode()
  File "/Users/dariuscognac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 409, in check_returncode
    self.stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Users/dariuscognac/Documents/GitHub/tezos/tezos-client', '-base-dir', '/var/folders/r5/yk8yg2xs1gs8xzkn5l8vr72w0000gn/T/tezos-client.ua4dn6on', '-endpoint', 'http://localhost:18730', 'transfer', '0', 'from', 'bootstrap1', 'to', 'main_contract', '--entrypoint', 'run', '--burn-cap', '9', '--arg', '42']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
(venv) $
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it would be greatly appreciated!

Collatz contracts in Michelson: 
onEven contract: https://bit.ly/3l6nbqj 
onOdd contract: https://bit.ly/3jn8Ghm 
main Collatz contract https://bit.ly/33l6i5i

 
Python tezos-sandbox test script: https://bit.ly/2GrOgoU

and for reference the SmartPy script: https://bit.ly/3nej7pN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in the SmartPy template (just discovered it).

You should either:

- add other entry points to onEven and onOdd;
- or remove the specification of `sp.contract(..., entry_point = "run")` in the main contract.

Comment: Ah okay. So I tried it with other entrypoints on onEven and onOdd. I just created another identical entry point to 'run' but called it dummy. I got a very similar but slightly different error. 

https://pastebin.com/u2vdMVN4

I tried the other method but that didn't work either, it gave the same error 
https://pastebin.com/dvdZfVFF

Comment: I just added the analysis (in the SmartPy interpreter) of the unique entry_point (long due) and SmartPy now catches you properly. There is another bug in the template (sigh...): you need to put `sp.set_type(params.x, sp.TNat)` in onOdd and onEven which should be caught by the SmartPy interpreter (the interpreter currently doesn't care). The template has been updated.

Comment: fantastic, i just tried it and it worked. Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you for reporting this!

Answer (score 1):

When you originated the Collatz contract, you needed two addresses for the initial storage; these two addresses have to be the addresses that you got when you originated the two previous contracts. Can you please show all the commands that you typed and all the answers that you got?

Comment: Thanks. I originated the three contracts and I believe the addresses were referenced properly in the Collatz contract on origination. 

I added all the code and all the output from running the test. (Let me know if there's a better way for sharing the code and output).

Comment: The error says that it fails here
```  36:                        CONTRACT %run (pair (contract %k nat) (nat %x)) ;
  37:                        IF_SOME {} { PUSH int 31 ; FAILWITH } ;
``` so line 31 (in the SmartPy script) of one of your contract in a `sp.contract` expression because the type is wrong.